# PPTP VPN to Tor

Tags: configuration, mac, vpn, mobile

I have a Mac OS X server with a PPTP VPN server running. I want to connect my iPhone to Tor by routing all traffic via my VPN server.

How can I configure my server to route the outgoing traffic over Tor?

Comment: Probably more details would help - mainly on which platform are you running the VPN gateway and on which (the same) do you intend to run the Tor client/gateway?

Comment: Currently my server runs OSX, but I suppose the configuration is almost the same as Linux, my Tor client runs on the same system.

Comment: Was this question resolved? If so, I'd like to hear your conclusion.

Comment: just use a firewall and [this](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/1/6/osx-wifi-proxy/) and [that](http://serverfault.com/questions/524875/enabling-pf-for-transparent-proxy-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion) tutorials to make it. Alternatively you can use a PF+TransPort mode. Take a look at [this](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/) program